# Error invalid architecture 'arm' when app from command line + iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, xcodebuild

I want to build an iOS app from command line with iOS simulator.

```
The build settings are:
1. Architectures - armv7
2. Base SDK - Latest IOS(6.1)
3. Build Active Architecture only - yes
4. Valid architectures - armv7 (also tried adding i386)
5. IOS deployment target - IOS 4.3
```

I am executing the following command:

```
xcodebuild -target splistapp2 -sdk iphonesimulator6.1 -configuration Release (also tried with  -arch "i836")
```

But this command gives following error:

```
invalid architecture 'arm' for deployment target '-mios-simulator-version-min=4.2'
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you try adding it to the "architectures" as opposed to the "valid architectures"?  Also to use the -arch flag, you need to have it in your valid architectures AND pass the flag (I don't know if you tried both at once)

Comment: yes i tried. not working.

Comment: Well the error message is pretty clear.  I use a very similar command in my build script and it works just fine.  Are you sure you are editing the correct target (and the correct configuration i.e. debug vs release).  Without physically seeing it we can only take your word on what the settings are (and I don't trust most people on SO to write correct information...)

Comment: For what it's worth though, I just checked and I have build active architecture only set to "no"

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone running into the same annoying problem again, I will share my script here: Remember to run this command under the directory that has the xcodeproj file.

```
xcodebuild \
-project "full-path-to-your-xcodeproj-file" \
-target YOUR_TARGET \
-sdk iphonesimulator6.1 \
-arch i386 \
-configuration Debug \
VALID_ARCHS="armv6 armv7 i386" \
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY="1" \
clean install
```

I modified the TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY because I only build for iPhone. If you want to build for both iPhone and iPad, delete this line or replace with TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY="1, 2".

Answer (score 1):

The device uses ARM; while the simulator uses i386. Pick one or the other:

- iphonesimulator6.1 and arch i386
- iphoneos and arch armv7 (or armv7s)

Answer (score 0):

Implement using arch1386 architecture.

> xcodebuild -project splistapp2 -target TEST_TARGET -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration "Debug" -arch i386